Using LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX with the LaTeX Workshop VS Code Extension
I'm using TeX Live 2024, and I'm trying to specify a custom font (Adobe Garamond Pro) I've just installed on my Mac OS Sonoma through double-clicking on the OTF files. An MWE of what I'm doing looks like this:
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Adobe Garamond Pro}

\begin{document}
  Hello There
\end{document}

Apparently, I cannot use the fontspec package unless I use either XeTeX or LuaLaTeX, which is the error message I'm getting on VS Code's output console through the LaTeX Workshop extension.
I do have both XeTeX and LuaLaTeX installed here (I think they come with TeX Live 2024), but how do I configure the LaTeX Workshop extension to use it? I haven't found anything going through the related settings.json options, and I haven't found a useful issue on their Github repo yet.

Here's the output of lualatex on the command line, which does work:
lualatex ./src/mwe.tex -o mwe.pdf                                                                                                                            

This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.18.0 (TeX Live 2024) 
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./src/mwe.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-02-20>
 (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls
Document Class: book 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/bk10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-luatex.def)))
 (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-luatex.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))
(./mwe.aux) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
(./mwe.toc) [1{/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex
.map}] [2] [3] [4]
Chapter 1.
[1] (./mwe.aux))
 411 words of node memory still in use:
   3 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 2 glue, 3 kern, 1 glyph, 4 attribute, 49 glue_spec
, 4 attribute_list, 1 write nodes
   avail lists: 2:57,3:38,4:2,5:28,6:6,7:130,9:32,10:1,11:2
</Users/phili/Library/Fonts/AGaramondPro-Italic.otf></Users/phili/Library/Fonts
/AGaramondPro-Regular.otf></Users/phili/Library/Fonts/AGaramondPro-Bold.otf>
Output written on mwe.pdf (5 pages, 10105 bytes).
Transcript written on mwe.log.

And here's the one for xelatex, which does work as well:
xelatex ./src/mwe.tex -o mwe2.pdf                                                                                                                            

This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999996 (TeX Live 2024) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./src/mwe.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-02-20>
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls
Document Class: book 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/bk10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-xetex.def)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-xetex.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))
(./mwe.aux) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
(./mwe.toc) [1] [2] [3] [4]
Chapter 1.
[1] (./mwe.aux) )
Output written on mwe.pdf (5 pages).
Transcript written on mwe.log.


If I try @AlanMunn's tip with % !TEX TS-program = lualatex at the beginning of the file, it still doesn't work, this is what I get from the output console in VS Code:
Rc files read:
  NONE
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 31 Jan. 2024. Version 4.83.
No existing .aux file, so I'll make a simple one, and require run of *latex.
Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'...
Rule 'pdflatex':  Reasons for rerun
Category 'other':
  Rerun of 'pdflatex' forced or previously required:
    Reason or flag: 'Initial setup'

------------
Run number 1 of rule 'pdflatex'
------------
------------
Running 'pdflatex  -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error -recorder -output-directory="dist"  "/Users/phili/Code/go/tsumegos_para_iniciantes/src/mwe.tex"'
------------
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (TeX Live 2024) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(/Users/phili/Code/go/tsumegos_para_iniciantes/src/mwe.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-02-20>
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls
Document Class: book 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/bk10.clo)) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)))

/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty:95: Fatal Package fontspec Error: The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or
(fontspec)                      LuaTeX.
(fontspec)                      
(fontspec)                      You must change your typesetting engine to,
(fontspec)                      e.g., "xelatex" or "lualatex" instead of
(fontspec)                      "latex" or "pdflatex".

Type <return> to continue.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.95 \msg_fatal:nn {fontspec} {cannot-use-pdftex}
                                                 

Latexmk: Sometimes, the -f option can be used to get latexmk
  to try to force complete processing.
  But normally, you will need to correct the file(s) that caused the
  error, and then rerun latexmk.
  In some cases, it is best to clean out generated files before rerunning
  latexmk after you've corrected the files.
Latexmk: Getting log file 'dist/mwe.log'
Latexmk: Examining 'dist/mwe.fls'
Latexmk: Examining 'dist/mwe.log'
Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
  pdflatex: Command for 'pdflatex' gave return code 1
      Refer to 'dist/mwe.log' and/or above output for details


I've also posted this on LaTeX Workshop's Github repo (Issue #4392).


If you have LaTeXWorkshop installed in VSCode, you should be able to just add % !TEX TS-program = lualatex at the beginning of the file and it should find the right recipe. Unlike in other editors, the tool is case-sensitive, so must be all lower case. (Many other editors allow e.g. LuaLaTeX but VSCode doesn't.)

@AlanMunn, interesting. Unfortunately, I tried it and it still doesn't work.

Your tip is quite similar to this other answer, and I couldn't make that run either.

What does "doesn't work" mean? Does it it not find the tool? Or does continue to compile using pdflatex?  Can you confirm that you have the tool in your LaTeXWorkshop settings.json?

Well, the output stops at where I shared, and nothing happens, no output file (PDF). What do you mean by "have the tool"? Which tool?

LaTeXWorkshop has two arrays in the settings file settings.json. One array is latex-workshop.latex.tools which should contain a tool named lualatex (and also lualatexmk). Additionally, it has an array called latex-workshop.latex.recipes which allows sets of tools to be combined. In my settings file I have a lualatex tool and also a lualatex recipe, which simply calls the lualatex tool.

Addtionally, and I think this is your problem, there is a setting latex-workshop.latex.build.forceRecipeUsage which is default set to true, which causes magic comments to be ignored. A weird default. Set this to false to use the magic comments.

I'm trying to use latex-workshop.latex.recipes and latex-workshop.latex.tools to configure things more programmatically, but haven't had much success so far. Doing things manually from the activity bar, as James Yu himself mentioned in the respective issue, has worked.

Going through LaTeX Workshop's documentation, while keeping in mind @AlanMunn's and James Yu's tips, I think the easiest way to more or less solve this is:

Use this in your VS Code's config "latex-workshop.latex.recipe.default": "lastUsed".
Go to VS Code's activity bar and manually click on whatever recipe you would like to use. Now, that last recipe you clicked is gonna be considered the default.

Ideally, I think that probably the least manual way of dealing with this would be to create your own recipe (latex-workshop.latex.recipes), but I haven't gotten around to making that work.
For the naming of the recipes, they seem to be using the same names as they appear on VS Code's Activity Bar. And thus using something like this would make things more programmatic:
{
    "latex-workshop.latex.recipe.default": "latexmk (lualatex)"
}

